# What is this young adult book series?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I remember reading a young adult series  probably 10 years ago, with quite a few books in the series. My memory is very fuzzy but I will try my best. One thing I remember above all else is that it creeped me out.

In the first book, a colonizing space ship leaves Earth with maybe 100 people, perhaps with some sort of cryogenic sleep. The ship lands on an unkown alien planet, where I remember there was something dangerous about the grass or environment. In successive books, colonists even die or disappear. In one book there is a scene referencing the tower of babel (I think?), hellish terrain and creatures like imps.

I vaguely remember a protaganist becoming pregnant, and that being an important theme, but I could be wrong.

A lot of the series reminds me of a Salvador Dali painting or something, very abstract with a hint of creepiness. If I can remember more I will edit the question. Sorry my question is so vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I hear about a young adult series involving generation ships, my brain tends to go to K. A. Applegate's *[Remnants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnants_(novel_series))* series. Coincidentally, it could be a decent match. One of the characters, Tamara Hoyle, gives birth during the series and it is plot relevant. The characters develop surreal powers such as one girl's mouth stretching large enough to eat her companions when she's stressed, so that might match, as does the timeframe.

> Remnants is a series of science fiction books written by K. A. Applegate between July 2001 and September 2003. It is the story of what happens to the survivors of a desperate mission to save a handful of human beings after an asteroid collides with the Earth. Eighty people are placed aboard a converted space shuttle using untested "quack" hibernation technology and fired blindly into space hours before all life on Earth is obliterated by a large asteroid called The Rock. They are then picked up by a large, sentient space craft of monumental proportions known as 'Mother' which is inhabited by various races. 'Mother' can manipulate the physical environment within the craft's limits and often does so. Only a few people placed in stasis actually were alive and capable of being reanimated when they reached 'Mother'.

Comment: Thats it! I can't believe it. This has been gnawing at me for a couple years now, I didn't think anyone would identify it with the few details I remembered. Great job!