# Looking for a YA book series about teenagers who are the only ones to survive hypersleep

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, soft-sci-fi

I read this series back in the early 2000s - sometime between 2003 and 2010. There were a ton of them, thin paperbacks. Some of them focused on different characters.

The plot that I remember: Earth was ending and they sent a space shuttle out to a habitable planet, but most of the people died in hypersleep. A few of them, all teenagers I believe, wake up and end up on a planet where some of them develop superpowers. I vaguely remember one girl's consciousness ending up in someone else's brain so she could only think to the other person for communication. There were aliens on this planet, but I don't remember them being humanoid. I think there were different groups forming and a lot of infighting between the kids. I think it ended with them growing up, some of them had kids and they had established a new kind of civilization on this planet.

Does anyone know what this is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Borrowing from my answer at [What is this young adult book series?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187488/what-is-this-young-adult-book-series/187493#187493):

When I hear about a young adult series involving generation ships, my brain tends to go to K. A. Applegate's *[Remnants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remnants_(novel_series))* series. Coincidentally, it could be a decent match. One of the characters, Tamara Hoyle, gives birth during the series and it is plot relevant. The characters develop surreal powers such as one girl's mouth stretching large enough to eat her companions when she's stressed, so that might match, as does the timeframe.

> Remnants is a series of science fiction books written by K. A. Applegate between July 2001 and September 2003. It is the story of what happens to the survivors of a desperate mission to save a handful of human beings after an asteroid collides with the Earth. Eighty people are placed aboard a converted space shuttle using untested "quack" hibernation technology and fired blindly into space hours before all life on Earth is obliterated by a large asteroid called The Rock. They are then picked up by a large, sentient space craft of monumental proportions known as 'Mother' which is inhabited by various races. 'Mother' can manipulate the physical environment within the craft's limits and often does so. Only a few people placed in stasis actually were alive and capable of being reanimated when they reached 'Mother'.